# PHP Post Selected Quantity to Table

Tags: php, mysql

I am relatively new to PHP, and web programming in general. I am having an issue when I attempt to take selected quantities of items from one page, and post the each selection and the quantity selected in a table on a separate PHP page. From there, I need to display the selections, selected quantity, price and the total. If anyone is able to help guide me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it! I have narrowed my issues down so that when I select the number of each selection and click "Submit" it will not process and add all of my selections to the table. Thank you in advance for the time and effort!

website 03 shop.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("website 03 library.php");
pagetop("WE WANT YOU TO SHOP");
echo "<span id = 'message' class = 'message'>Select How Many You Want of Each Product</span>";
$host_name = "localhost";
$user_name = "web";
$password = "programming";
$database = "assignments";
$connection = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
$sql = "select * from products";
$recordSet = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array ($recordSet, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $pid = $record['pid'];
    echo "<form action = 'website 03 cart.php' method = 'post'>";
    echo "<h2 name = 'NAME$pid'>$record['name']</h2><br><br>";
    echo "<img name = 'IMAGE$pid' style = 'height:280px; width:350px; ' src = '$record['url']'><br><br>";
    echo "<span name = 'PRICE$pid'>Price of each $record['name'] is $record['price']. How many do you want? </span>";
    echo "<select name = 'QUANTITY$pid'>";
        echo "<option value = 0>0</option>";
        echo "<option value = 1>1</option>";
        echo "<option value = 2>2</option>";
        echo "<option value = 3>3</option>";
        echo "<option value = 4>4</option>";
    echo "</select>";
    echo "<input type = 'submit' class = 'button' name = 'SUBMIT$pid' value = 'SUBMIT'>";
    echo "</form>";
};
mysqli_free_result($recordSet);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

Second page (receiving the selected values)

website 03 cart.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include("website 03 library.php");
pagetop("SHOPPING CART");
$host_name = "localhost";
$user_name = "web";
$password = "programming";
$database = "assignments";
$connection = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);

echo "<table border = 1>";
$sql = "select * from products";
$recordSet = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($recordSet, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $pid = $record['pid'];
    $url = $record['url'];
    $price = $record['price'];
    $key = "QUANTITY$pid";
    $quantity = $_POST['$key'];
    $total = $quantity * $price;
    if ($quantity > 1) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><img style = 'height:110; width:150; ' src = $url></td>";
        echo "<td>$quantity</td>";
        echo "<td>$price</td>";
        echo "<td>$total</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>TOTAL:</td>";
        echo "<td>$total</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "</tr>";
    };
};
echo "</table>";
?>
```

My intention is to take the posted data from 03 shop and place it in a table in 03 cart. Sort of like an online store. Where I would, for example, select 2 "clocks" and 3 "bicycles" and then that data would be posted into a table in 03 cart in the order: image, quantity, price and total (quantity * price). I believe my issue is that the "submit" button is within the loop, so it will only post from one section. But, I do not know how I could use the "submit" button to reference all of the selections in one post, to website 03 cart.

Comment: do you have access to your php_error_log?  the errors will guide you.

Comment: @WEBjuju unfortunately I do not. I am coding within a website created by a professor at my university. When I submit the assignment, it shows the process and steps it goes through to check my pages. This is how I know it will no longer process once more than one selection is made on the first page. The grading process states it clicks the "Submit" button, but nothing after that.

Comment: hmm, i see.  well, you can download [xampp](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwitqfmt8OXQAhXHNiYKHfaYACwQjBAIIzAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.apachefriends.org%2Fdownload.html&usg=AFQjCNEqFzBnZ4FDvJamdKo3NK9N7iWK0Q) and then you can use a real programming environment where the errors actually tell you what's wrong.  then when you have the assignment correct, you can submit the code - and hit submit.

Comment: btw, without `$` a variable is a constant.  so `$record[price];` is only valid if you have `define('price', '15.00')`;  all those places where you have an array element that is missing quoting or a `$`...they are probably wrong.  change to `$record['price'];` with quotes for best results.

Comment: @WEBjuju thanks for the tip! I am pulling those values from a table within a database table and not looking to define them in the page itself. Would I still need to use the single quotation marks?

Comment: strickly speaking, no.  but your choice is `"` or `'`.  `"` are processed twice to look for embedded variables, so they are slower, on a technical level.  many developers think `"` are easier to read and use them probably due to that fact.  it's personal preference, but i'm a single quoter.

Comment: @WEBjuju I will keep that in mind, but I do agree. It does seem easier to read.

Comment: if you want to fix those variables and update your post (without putting all the extra lines back), i'll have another look.  also, it will help if you name your files, for instance, i couldn't say for sure that your form action was pointed properly.

Comment: @WEBjuju I went through the two pages and added the single quotes in to the variables that were taken from my separate database table. I also included the names of each page above the code. Does that help?

Comment: take the single quotes off this `$_POST['$key'];`.  you **WANT** the variable there.

Comment: you need to add to teh post at this point some kind of response or output or explanation of what it still is not doing properly.

Comment: @WEBjuju yes. My intention is to take the posted data from 03 shop and place it in a table in 03 cart. Sort of like an online store. Where I would, for example, select 2 "clocks" and 3 "bicycles" and then that data would be posted into a table in 03 cart in the order: image, quantity, price and total (quantity * price). I believe my issue is that the "submit" button is within the loop, so it will only post from one section. But, I do not know how I could use the "submit" button to reference all of the selections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your `<form>` tag outside the loop, change your `03 shop` `while` loop to have the `<form>` tag outside the loop.

Also note that `$variables` which are complex like `$record['name']` cannot be embedded in double quotes without curly braces like this: `{$record['name']}`.

```
// print the form open 
echo "<form action = 'website 03 cart.php' method = 'post'>";
// do the loop
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array ($recordSet, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
  $pid = $record['pid'];

  // complex vars inside double quotes require special syntax
  echo "<h2 name = 'NAME$pid'>{$record['name']}</h2><br><br>";

  echo "<img name = 'IMAGE$pid' style = 'height:280px; width:350px; ' src = '{$record['url']}'><br><br>";
  echo "<span name = 'PRICE$pid'>Price of each {$record['name']} is {$record['price']}. How many do you want? </span>";
  echo "<select name = 'QUANTITY$pid'>";
    echo "<option value = 0>0</option>";
    echo "<option value = 1>1</option>";
    echo "<option value = 2>2</option>";
    echo "<option value = 3>3</option>";
    echo "<option value = 4>4</option>";
  echo "</select>";
  echo "<input type = 'submit' class = 'button' name = 'SUBMIT' value = 'SUBMIT'>";
};
// now close the form
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: This was very helpful! My issue from this point on is that my professor is grading the assignment so that there is a "submit" button after each product. The solution above places the "submit" button after all of the products have been sent to the page. Any suggestions? I'm not sure it's even possible when I think about it. Maybe my logic/functions should be changed?

Comment: you can have the submit after every product, it doesn't matter. i'll update it.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: cool, best of luck. i pray you become the best programmer that ever was.

Comment: As long as I become at least half as knowledgable as you, I think I'll be on the right track! Thanks again

Comment: we all have islands of knowledge ;) no worries, glad to help